# Replace the text with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

**From this code.**

```
<form method="get">
    <div align="center"><textarea name="post" ></textarea></div>
    <div align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
</form>

<?
$aaa = $post;
$new_aaa=str_replace(array(
'a', 
'b'
), array(
'A',
'B'
), $aaa);
?>

<textarea readonly="true" cols="100" rows="3" name="post" >
    <? echo $new_aaa; ?>
</textarea>
</div>
```

If we write in the form of javascript to do here?
If you do not understand, it is to get value from `textarea` and then use the `str_replace` function as a type, but the output is A, help me write a little PHP I own one, but never wrote JS.

Sorry for bad English, I've used Google Translate.

Comment: Do you only want to replace 'a' by 'A' and 'b' by 'B', or just make the textarea text all uppercase? Do you want to modify the textarea text when focus leaves the textarea?

Comment: Are you asking to convert the functionality of the above code from PHP to Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method="get" onSubmit='Convert()'>
    <div align="center"><textarea name="post" id="post" ></textarea></div>
    <div align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
</form>
```

........ In script

```
<script>
function Convert()
{
  var p = document.getElementById ("post").value;
 p =  p.replace(/a/g,”A”);
 p =  p.replace(/b/g,”B”);

document.getElementById ("post").value= p;

}
</script>
```

Comment: IIRC Convert() needs to return false or you won't see the result.

Comment: Now I can do then.
Thank you all comments.

Answer (score 0):

Now I can do then.

Thank you all comments.

---

```
<form method="get" onsubmit="return Convert();">
    <div align="center"><textarea name="post" id="post" ></textarea></div>
    <div align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
</form>

<script>
function Convert()
{

    var p = document.getElementById ("post").value;

    var replace = {
        '1' : "\u0e45",
        '2' : "\u002F",
    };
    for(var i in replace)
    {
        var regex = new RegExp(i,'g');
        p =  p.replace(regex,replace[i]);
    }
    document.getElementById ("post2").value= p;
    return false;
}
</script>
<textarea readonly="true" cols="100" rows="3" name="post2" id="post2" >
</textarea>
```

Comment: Add 4 spaces or a tab to each line of code, then you get code highlighting